# Is it good practise to highlight step number instead of step name in multi step form design?

Tags: usability, gui-design, multi-step, steps

[image]

Is it a good practise to highlight step number more compare to your step name? In my current example, we have step no. highlighted and bigger in size that it gets all attention. Not sure if this is a good practice or we can reduce the step no. and increase the size of step name or give kind of more highlight to step name.

Looking forward to your suggestions/view.

Answer (score 1):

Keeping the user informed in any way possible is always a good thing. In your case, double coding (numbered image and text) is preferred. Having the bottom bar visible through all the steps is a very good thing. Moreover, if you’re into e-commerce, this is the number one thing to keep conversion rates as high as possible.

## Example of e-commerce checkout

Sorry for being in Swedish. Steg = Step

[image]

The opposite, disclosing number of steps, makes the user confused. We’ve all taken online surveys which were too long and where we couldn’t see the end.

Comment: addressing just a small part of your fine answer, I think it's quite the opposite, most research I have seen shows it's preferably to have "Step 1 of...." than just "Step 1". And you explained yourself: "We’ve all taken online surveys which were too long and where we couldn’t see the end". Providing the end, makes the user comfortable (unless of course, the steps are so lengthly you need to hide the amount of steps just not to scare the user, in which case you need to prevent the user "this will take x amount of minutes")